# Why did my candies disappear for no reason?

Tags: pokemon-go

Overnight, 13 Dratini candies, representing 65 km of walking, disappeared for no reason. No Pokémon were accidentally evolved, no CP was added to Pokémon in that line of evolution. Just gone. No response from Niantic yet. Anyone else see something like this?

Comment: Suppose someone did see something like this... how would that be helpful? Likely a bug or sync issue. You're probably SOL, considering how Niantic will be _very_ eager to help you with missing candies.

Comment: @JeffMercado He's not alone... I lost near 20 pokeballs that I clearly had in my inventory. I'm aware it's probably a sync bug, that I never had those balls... But still.

Comment: @Karlyr: Yeah, I'm sure others may have experienced problems with this game - as it has been since it launched - but it won't help to ask about it with other players. "Why did this happen?" "The game is still broken" All we can do at this point is act as a support group and pile on the "that happened to me too" comments which achieves nothing.

Comment: Did you already send a bug report ?